# Accord.Net throws Null Reference Exception when deserializing an instance of Codification

Tags: c#, accord.net

Using Accord.Net, I am trying to Serialize/Deserialize an instance of the Codification class but receive a Null Reference Exception when attempting to Deserialize. I have not had issues when serializing the object.  If the instance does not have columns initialized, no exception is thrown.

```
 System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Accord
  StackTrace:
       at Accord.Collections.TwoWayDictionary`2.OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationEventHandler.Invoke(StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RaiseDeserializationEvent()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
```

I used the example table from the NaiveBayes to test

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Mitchell's Tennis Example");

        table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]{
            new DataColumn("Day", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Outlook", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Temperature", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Humidity", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Wind", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("PlayTennis", typeof(string))});

        table.Rows.Add("D1", "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "No");
        table.Rows.Add("D2", "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong", "No");
        table.Rows.Add("D3", "Overcast", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "Yes");
        table.Rows.Add("D4", "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "Yes");
        table.Rows.Add("D5", "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
        table.Rows.Add("D6", "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "No");
        table.Rows.Add("D7", "Overcast", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes");
        table.Rows.Add("D8", "Sunny", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "No");
        table.Rows.Add("D9", "Sunny", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
        table.Rows.Add("D10", "Rain", "Mild", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
        table.Rows.Add("D11", "Sunny", "Mild", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes");
        table.Rows.Add("D12", "Overcast", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "Yes");
        table.Rows.Add("D13", "Overcast", "Hot", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
        table.Rows.Add("D14", "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "No");


        Codification codebook = new Codification(table);

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, codebook);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object test = bf.Deserialize(ms);    //Exception thrown here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That code runs fine for me - looks like [the problem was fixed in 3.3.0](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/285)